# GUI and user interaction for Scrapy+Splash (osx)

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm looking for a way to be able to interact with Scrapy+Splash. Something like opening a browser window and see what is happening, but also click around if needed.

Is there a good way for this?

The method from

https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kernel.html#live-webkit-window

didn't work.